# How to transform a recursive method that prints to the console, so that it returns a string?

Tags: java, recursion

Hello everyone and thanks for your help in advance.
I have this recursive method that prints in console.

```
private void printPath(Vertex destiny) {
        if (destiny.getPrevious() != null) {
            printPath(destiny.getPrevious());
            System.out.print(" to ");
        }
        System.out.print(destiny.getName());
    }
```

But now I need to return the concatenated String instead of printing.
I have this poor attempt ...

```
private String printPath(Vertex destiny, String concat) {
        if (destiny.getPrevious() == null) {
            return " , " + concat;
        } else {
            return printPath(destiny, (destiny.getName() + " " + concat));
        }
    }
```

But I can not make it work, it gives me a StackOverflowException.

Edit:
The output to console is for example:
"Spain to Germany to Poland to Greece" ...
And it's the same thing I want to return in a String.

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you provide the output of your console as well (what you are getting now and what you are expecting).

Comment: In your first code example, you call `printPath` on `getPrevious()`.  You're not doing it in the second case.

Comment: In your second code what would be the value of the second argument `concat` when `printPath` called for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is not getting terminated correctly, try this:

```
private String printPath(Vertex destiny, String concat) {
    if (destiny.getPrevious() == null) {
        return " , " + concat;
    } else {
        return printPath(destiny.getPrevious(), (destiny.getName() + " " + concat));
    }
}
```

Pass `destiny.getPrevious()` instead of `destiny` to the method.

Comment: I believe that Sriram is right. Look at what you passed back into printPath, your original answer will lead to an infinite loop if the first vertex has a previous vertex

Comment: Thank you very much! @SriramKailasam
In fact I had forgotten to include     getPrevious() on the second return and that caused an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
private StringBuilder printPath(Vertex destiny, StringBuilder path) {
        if (destiny.getPrevious() != null) {
            printPath(destiny.getPrevious(), path);
            path.append(" to ")  ;
        }
        path.append(destiny.getName());
        return path;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting output as "Spain to Germany to Poland to Greece"

Case 1: if destiny.getPrevious() == null then it will return destiny.getName() only as in your first code.

Case 2: if destiny.getPrevious() != null then it will return first element to last element

```
private String printPath(Vertex destiny, String concat) {
    if (destiny.getPrevious() == null) {
        return destiny.getName() + concat;
    } else {
        return printPath(destiny.getPrevious(), (" to " + destiny.getName() + concat));
    }
}
```